# Load and insert a script, when scrolling to this point on the page

Tags: javascript, optimization, scroll

I have this script but it duplicates the scripts when scrolling, does anyone know how I can modify it so that it only inserts this script once when the user scrolls, look at the image, it is a Google script for RGPD
Get started getting GDPR consent and manage your settings
THIS SCRIPT HARMS THE OPTIMIZATION OF Lighthouse AND PageSpeed Insights.. I have searched and this script helps to optimize but it injects the scripts too many times.. Can someone help me, thanks...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d7T8.jpg)

insert a script, when scrolling to this point on the page.
and I was expecting you to insert this script
when the user scrolls the web, to optimize the loading of the web...

`````
<script>
var scrollFromTop = $("#cargars").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  > scrollFromTop) {       
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        s.src = 'https://fundingchoicesmessages.google.com/i/pub-9225993600367994';
        document.getElementById('cargars').appendChild(s);
    }
});
</script>````
`````

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this question????
or any idea how to improve the script so that it doesn't duplicate it infinite times...

Comment: You have added insertion on any scroll action of the document, so every time you scroll, a script is added.
You should add a flag indicating that your script has already been added, and check for that flag with the first condition.